# ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) type "json" does not exist

Tags: python, sql, json, pandas, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to upload a pandas table with a json column into redshift. Here is a simplified version.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.types import JSON
import pandas as pd

RS_creds = {}

RS_creds['host'] = %env RS_DATA_HOST
RS_creds['user'] = %env RS_DATA_USER
RS_creds['pass'] = %env RS_DATA_PASS
RS_creds['port'] = %env RS_DATA_PORT
RS_creds['db'] = %env RS_DATA_DB

test = pd.DataFrame([[1, json.dumps({"a": "A1", "b": "B1"})], [2, json.dumps({"a": "A2", "b": "B2"})]])
test.columns = ['x', 'y']

url = f"postgresql://{RS_creds['user']}:{RS_creds['pass']}@{RS_creds['host']}:5439/{RS_creds['db']}"

conn = create_engine(url)

test.to_sql('test', conn, schema = 'test', index = False, dtype={'y': JSON})
```

This throws an error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) type "json" does not exist

[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE test.test (
    x BIGINT, 
    y JSON
)

]
```

My actual table is uploaded from MySQL and i tried adding things like

`from psycopg2.extras import Json`

but no luck.

Comment: Your sample file shows `import mysql.connector as conn`.  You should delete that to avoid confusion.

Comment: @TimRoberts I did "postgres --version" and it came back with "postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.6 (Homebrew)"

Comment: Yes, but that's your local system.  That's not the server you're talking to, which is on redshift's system.  See below.

Comment: noooooooo :((((( so is there no way to upload a pandas with json column using to_sql? I'm being told here that a "super" column is required.

Comment: Not with redshift, No.  You can certainly store it as a VARCHAR column; it just means you can't do JSON-based queries on the server.  To the serveri, it would just be a dumb string.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift does not support the JSON data type.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html